# Managing Source and Class Files in Java

Tags: java, class

I'm relatively new to Java and programming in general, so my question may seem obvious, but I am trying to learn.

To make it short, there are `.class` files in my source folder.

I work in Eclipse and I'm not sure how they got there. I've always had the output directory in a `bin` folder rather than the `src` folder. Based on Windows, those `.class` files haven't been changed in over a month.

Would anyone suggest removing them to make the work space a little bit neater?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they have corresponding `.java` files?

Comment: .class file is compiled .java file, if you have original .java you can always delete your .class files and compile new

Comment: Yes, each `.class` file is right above its `.java` file in the Windows Explorer, but with different last modified dates. Every `.class` file in the `src` folder has the same last modified date.

Comment: @JeffSpell Then it should be safe to remove the `.class` files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can always remove the .class files - Eclipse will just remake them at the right time.

To change where they are stored, right-mouse on your project in the Package Explorer and select `Build Path > Configure Build Path`.  Click on the "Source" tab.  The output folder is listed at the bottom of the tab.